# Makefile rule with multiple targets for single invocation

Tags: makefile, target

According to the [gnu make documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Multiple-Targets.html#Multiple-Targets), if a rule generates multiple targets by a single invocation (for instance with a recipe executing a tool with multiple output files), you can use the '&:' rule syntax to tell make.
I'm getting warnings when using this syntax, about target '&', however, when having multiple (but unique) targets in multiple rules. As if make mistakes the ampersand for a target name instead of being part of the target-prerequisite separator.

In my original project I've got two rules having multiple targets and *a recipe generating those targets from a single statement/tool*. The targets are unique for each of the two rules. I've created the following simple example to demonstrate the warning generated by make:

```
all: file_abbc

.PHONY: all clean

clean:
    del /Q file_*

file_abbc: file_ab file_bc
    copy file_ab+file_bc file_abbc

file_ab file_bc &: file_a file_b file_c
    copy file_a+file_b file_ab
    copy file_b+file_c file_bc

file_a file_b file_c &: content
    copy content file_a
    copy content file_b
    copy content file_c
```

Warnings from running make on Windows on the above:

> Makefile:17: warning: overriding recipe for target '&'
>
> Makefile:13: warning: ignoring old recipe for target '&'

Why is make complaining about target '&' ?

Comment: You're using an old version of GNU make that doesn't understand `&:` rules, so just treats `&` as a file name.  Use `make --version` to see which version you are running and upgrade if it is older that 4.3

Comment: @ChrisDodd That's useful. I tried both 3.81 and 4.2.90 and had the same results. I was in fact wondering why the make documentation doesn't state the minimum version for each feature, but I see now that the documentation I linked to is for 4.3. It seems many systems by default have lesser versions, though.

Comment: Well, tough luck that I discovered the '&:' feature 2 weeks ago, which was just released 3 weeks ago in make 4.3.. No wonder it isn't supported by the make versions I already have.

Comment: If this example follows your real Makefile, than there is no need for `&:`. Each of those can be generated in a separate rule as there is no single statement that generates more than one file.

Comment: @raspy true. My real Makefile is using a couple of tools that generate multiple targets from a single recipe statement, which I tried to say in the first sentence of my question. I'll edit to make it clearer.

Comment: @ChrisDodd care to add your comment as a proper answer, or should I? :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're using an old version of GNU make that doesn't understand `&:` rules, so just treats `&` as a file name. Use `make --version` to see which version you are running and upgrade if it is older that 4.3

Comment: Thanks! I was running into the same issue and this fixed it.